# Problem using WiFi to install Home Assistant on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: wifi, software-installation

Please do not reply to this if you think I am being difficult because I do not want to use Ethernet to install Home Assistant. (I know that the recommended method is to install HA using Ethernet but I can't do that.)

I am attempting to install Home Assistant using Mac OS to create the SD. The Mac only creates a GUID Partition Table SD. I also tried to use Linux but had the same problem. I was advised to use Imager custom img and the advanced options - which I am.

If I use the advanced options and a custom HA img, the install script times out at `Starting Docker Application Container Engine`

with this message `Wait Until Time Time Synchronized`

Has anyone successfully installed Home Assistant using WiFi?

Comment: So this is a problem on a Mac; not a Pi?

Comment: Are you certain that WiFi is connected before the install script starts?

Comment: The problem is both -  I have problems creating an SD on my Mac, but the script executes until Kernel Time Synchronizaton.

Comment: There is no way (that I know of) for wifi to be connected before the script starts. The script is supposed to do that.

Comment: The install procedure discusses adding a CONFIG file to the SD but I can't do that because the Mac creates an unwritable GUD partition map on the SD.

Comment: We were able to modify the SD to add the CONFIG folder using Linux, but so far I have been unable to get past the HA CLI.

Comment: I used both the Home Assistant installer and Raspberry Pi installer (using Advanced options). Have you done this successfully using Mac OS?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is "using MacOS to create the SD".

Try using the Raspberry Pi installer.